# Why doesn't my vector layers show up when I put them under my raster layer in QGIS 3.12?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector

My vector layers do not appear in the raster year, do you know how could I fix this?

[image]

Comment: In the layers panel, drag your raster layers so they are positioned underneath all vector layers??

Comment: It looks aligned? The red dots are surrounding some fields?

Comment: @BERA, I agree about the alignment. I was confused by the title, but the question body mentions layers not appearing. The O.P. has several checked vector layers in the TOC which are underneath a raster layer. I think it's what he means?

Comment: Hello Ben and Bera, so I have my road layer but it doesn't appear in the raster layer, nor buildings, rivers, land use or protected areas. what is the O.P. mean?

Comment: Thank you for your answers

Comment: Drag the raster layer (named `3420C_...`) to the bottom. O. P. mean "Original Poster"="the asker of the question"="You".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of layers in QGIS Layer Panel determines what will be shown on top. Drag your raster layers to the bottom in the layers panel.

This is your layers panel:

[image]

Or if you really would like to have rasters on top, then make them partially transparent so that you can see through them.

Comment: Thank you! It works!

Comment: @Harold please accept the answer